# Using SELECTEDVALUE with PowerPivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I got help to the code below to create a measure in PowerPivot, but I'm running into errors because of `SELECTEDVALUE` which does not seem like a command I can use in Excel, anyone can help me around with this?

```
VAR SignUpMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Signup month] )
VAR MonthDiff =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( '1 through 24'[Value] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( [conversion to KYC completed] ),
            FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Month Diff] = MonthDiff )
        ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Table1[ signups] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Signup month] = SignUpMonth )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DAX function [`SELECTEDVALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) is a newer one that isn't supported in Excel yet, but the documentation linked gives an alternative that works the same way:

> An equivalent expression for `SELECTEDVALUE(<columnName>, <alternateResult>)` is `IF(HASONEVALUE(<columnName>), VALUES(<columnName>), <alternateResult>)`.

You can often just use `MAX` instead of `SELECTEDVALUE` if you don't need to return an `alternateResult` when there is more than one value to choose from.